# Add subtitle to embedded youtube video dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, jsf-2, youtube-api

I'm building a site with an embedded Youtube player using JSF. I want to load a text file that will act as a subtitle and appear on the player. I need to do this dynamically, because I don't know what video will be loaded.

My embedded player is:

```
<object width="425" height="344">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1"
     type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
     width="425" height="344">
</embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just find out that it's better to use the youtube as3 api and wrap it with a custom flash player;

so eventually all the logic happens in the action script  i can add, move , re size, etc on the player...